# Non-algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've been trying to find a set whose Zariski closure differs from its usual closure (that is, the closure in the topology induced from the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$) on a variety V.
My first idea was to consider V to be the unit circle and the set {$z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1 \wedge Im(z) \geq 0$}. If the set is not algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$, then its usual closure is equal to it while its Zariski closure is not, but i can't figure out a way to show if the set is algebraic or not.

Comment: You should study one in $\mathbb{C}^2$, otherwise what you are studying is not rich enough, basically the algebraically closed sets here are either $\mathbb{C}$ or finite sets, hence if you consider an infinite closed strict subset of $\mathbb{C}$ you have its Zariski's closure that is $\mathbb{C}$ (you can't have infinitely many roots) which is not its usual closure, but this is a trivial example